# $(\iota \otimes f)(X) = 0$ for all $f \in B^*$ implies $X=0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, multiplier-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be $C^*$-algebras. Given $f \in B^*$, we can form the right slice map
$$\iota \otimes f: A \otimes B \to A: a \otimes b \mapsto af(b)$$
which extends uniquely to a bounded linear map
$$\iota \otimes f: M(A \otimes B) \to M(A)$$
that is strictly continuous on the unit ball.

Assume $X \in M(A \otimes B)$ satisfies $(\iota \otimes f)(X)=0$ for all $f \in A^*$. Can we conclude that $X=0?$

**Attempt**: When $B$ is unital, we can proceed as follows: if $a\in A$
$$0 = (\iota\otimes f)(X)a = (\iota \otimes f)(X(a \otimes 1_B))$$ for all $f \in A^*$, so since $X(a \otimes 1_B) \in A \otimes B$ we conclude that $X(a \otimes 1_B)=0$. Hence, $X(A \otimes B) = 0$ which implies $X=0$.

How to deal with the case that $B$ is non-unital?

Comment: Think about a representation $A \otimes B \subset B(H\otimes K)$.

Comment: I would be interested to know what your _definition_ of the slice map is?

Comment: @MatthewDaws I think my post contains the definition. I first form the slice map $\iota \otimes f: A \otimes B \to A$ which is defined on pure tensors by $a \otimes b \mapsto a f(b)$. Routine arguments show that this really gives a bounded map defined on the minimal tensor product. Then, I define the slice map $\iota \otimes f: M(A \otimes B) \to M(A)$ to be the unique extension of the slice $A \otimes B \to A$ that is strictly continuous on bounded subsets.

Comment: Sorry, I meant, what reference (or if no reference, what argument) are you using to make, specifically, the "unique extension" which is "strictly continuous on bounded subsets".  I think it is not true that any bounded linear map so extends?

Comment: @MatthewDaws Call a linear map $f: A \to M(B)$ between $C^*$-algebras strict if it is strictly continuous on bounded subsets and norm-continuous. For such a map, it can be shown that such a unique extension exists. I guess if I look hard enough, I can find a reference. Now, the point is that the slice map $\iota \otimes f: A \otimes B \to A\subseteq M(A)$ satisfies this property. To see this, we may assume that $f$ is a state (because any functional is a linear combination of 4 states). Moreover, $f$ is strict. Then use that the tensor product of two strict c.p. maps is again strict.

Comment: I would be interested in a reference if you had one!!  The argument you then go on to sketch seems to be the same as that given by Lance in his book (reduce to the case when $f$ is positive, then $f$ is a CP map, so the machinery we already have applies).

Comment: @MatthewDaws In Lance's book, the most general case treated is the one of completely positive maps. You can do a lot more better than that (though often all you need is completely positive maps). Take a look at the appendix in the following article. It contains a lot of stuff that is hard to find explicitly elsewhere: https://arxiv.org/pdf/funct-an/9707009.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131535/discussion-between-matthew-daws-and-andromeda).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From comments, it seems that the OP is using the "abstract" definition of multipliers (compare below).  A good reference is indeed the appendix of [arXiv:funct-an/9707009](https://arxiv.org/abs/funct-an/9707009).  Let's use some remarks from there (bottom of page 38) to show that $\iota\otimes f:A\otimes B\rightarrow A$ is indeed strict.  By Cohen--Hewitt factorisation, we can find $g\in B^*, c\in B$ with $f = cg$, and so
$$ (\iota\otimes f)(a\otimes b) = f(b) a  = g(bc) a = (\iota\otimes g)(a\otimes bc) $$
Thus if $(u_i)$ is a bounded net in $A\otimes B$ converging strictly to $0$, for $a\in A$ we have that
$$ (\iota\otimes f)(u_i) a = (\iota\otimes g)(u_i(a\otimes c)) \rightarrow 0 $$
because $u_i(a\otimes c)\rightarrow 0$ in norm.

So we form the strict extension to $M(A\otimes B)$.  If $(u_i)$ is a bounded net in $A\otimes B$ converging strictly to $X\in M(A\otimes B)$ then by definition of the strict extension (or by strict continuity),
$$ (\iota\otimes f)(X) a = \lim_i (\iota\otimes f)(u_i) a \qquad (a\in A). $$
However, this is equal to
$$ \lim_i (\iota\otimes g)(u_i(a\otimes c)) = (\iota\otimes g)(X(a\otimes c)). $$
So if $(\iota\otimes f)(X)=0$ for all $f$, then $(\iota\otimes g)(X(a\otimes c)) = 0$ for all $g,c$ and $a$, and so $X(a\otimes c)=0$ for all $a,c$ so $X=0$.

(I think of this as the "factorisation trick".  Aside from CP maps, most examples of strict linear maps seem to feature some notion of "factorisation".)

---

Taka's comment was to use a representation of $A\otimes B$ on a Hilbert space.  This is the "centraliser" picture of multipliers: if $A\subseteq\mathcal B(H), B\subseteq\mathcal B(K)$ acting non-degenerately, then $A\otimes B\subseteq\mathcal B(H\otimes K)$ non-degenerately and
$$ M(A\otimes B) \cong \{ T\in\mathcal B(H\otimes K) : Tu, uT\in A\otimes B \ (u\in A\otimes B) \}. $$
This is independent of the representations chosen, so let's suppose that $f\in B^*$ is the restriction of $\omega_{\xi,\eta}$ to $B$.  Then we have a natural notion of what $(\iota\otimes f)$ is acting on $M(A\otimes B)$: just the restriction of $\iota\otimes\omega_{\xi,\eta}:\mathcal B(H\otimes K) \rightarrow \mathcal B(H)$.  Of course, you'd need to check that this gave the same definition as before.  The required result is now obvious.

Comment: Matthew, you are on fire!